# Making global CSS changes in SPO 2013 MySite

Tags: sharepoint-online, my-site, branding, mysite, mysites

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013 and I wanted to do some small CSS changes to MySites globally. I noticed that as the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature in the MySite root settings is not enabled, I can't enter the alternate style sheet in the settings via the settings menu and if I try to use direct url "...-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx" I get an error.

So my question has two parts. First is there a way to apply global CSS changes without activating the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature in MySite root level?

Secondly, if there isn't, are there any downsides in enabling the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" in MySite root level?

Thanks! :)

Comment: you mean globally to *your* MySite or global as in for everyone's MySites?

Comment: Globally for everyone's MySites. I did some more digging through google and I found some discouraging information about it being not possible? :/

Comment: usually this is done through a feature stapler, which appears to be unavailable for sp online. maybe there could be another way, but it won't be such straight-forward. you can change mysites with sharepoint designer, but this is after it has been created, not automatically on provisioning

Comment: Ok thank you for your information! You could create an answer with this comment and I'll keep this question open for a bit longer and if there won't be any other/new info regarding the problem, I will choose your answer as the correct one. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally I would do this through [feature stapling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861862%28v=office.12%29.aspx), however it [doesn't seem to be supported](http://sharepointrepairjoint.blogspot.se/2012/03/feature-stapling-in-sharepoint-online.html) in SPO/O365.

There may be some workarounds though.

If you are okay with doing it manually, you can create a [PowerShell script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161362%28v=office.15%29.aspx) that looks through your MySites and activates the branding features, and run it regularly.

Alternatively you can check [other solutions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34509/alternatives-to-feature-stapling), but for Online farms you may be conditioned to available features.

Finally, here's [another interesting article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2013/11/25/office365-apply-automatically-custom-branding-to-personal-site-skydrive-pro.aspx) on the subject. I'm just not sure if the keyword "automatically" in this case has the same meaning (e.g. automatically when you deploy the solution as opposed to when you create the site).

Comment: I haven't found anything else to solve this problem so I accept your answer as it has some really good information. Thank you Tiago so much for the help! :)

Comment: One more question though, I am a real newbie with PowerShell scripts so could you maybe write me the script or shine some light on it at least so I might get it working somehow? :)

Comment: you have several challenges. enumerating the sites, uploading the solution and enabling it. I dont think there are ootb cmdlets to do that, but maybe csom is the way to go. heres an example http://sadomovalex.blogspot.se/2014/07/upload-sandbox-solutions-to-sharepoint.html

Comment: Ok I will read that through, thank you very much for all your help. :)